# How to input data into Modal window using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

In my application, there is a login page. After logging in, system auto detects if it is a holiday; if it is a holiday, it opens one Modal window for login asking another user to put his credentials to authorize the first users login. Now the problem is, in my Java code, I am not able to switch to the new modal window for inputting the authorizer user id and password using Selenium. I have tried the following ways:

1) Using `wbParam.switchTo().activeElement();`

2)

```
Set<String> handles = wbParam.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println("number of windows"+handles.toString() + "Size is ::"+handles.size());
```

But size of the set is returned to me as 1, presumably the parent window.

3)

```
if(waitParam.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.name("validateForm"))) != null)
```

where `validateform` is the name of the `div` of the modal window.

Please note `wbParam` is the driver object.

Now how can I handle this scenario?

**UPDATE:** Apparently, `window.showModalDialog` does not work with Selenium according to the following thread, `https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/284`. Does anyone know any workaround for this?

Comment: `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy` returns `List<WebElement>`. It can't be used inside `if`. Try without the `if`, does it fail or locate the elements?

Comment: What exception does it throw ? Update the question with HTML code and error stack trace for further analysis. If possible share the screenshot in a link format of model window.

Comment: @Guy, sorry for wrong typing. I updated the code, the `if` condition checks `!=null` condition. Without the condition also, it fails to locate the element.

Comment: @cruisepandey, Actually I am unable to see the element. Because developer tool is not working while the modal window ha started in IE. Developer has only given me the `div` name.

Comment: Just check if the window is iframe? If it is, please try as: You are dealing with an iframe. Follow the below steps :
1. You'll need to switch control to the iframe.
2. Then perform your action. (Input required data).
3. Switch the control back to default frame.

Comment: @HemSa, How to know the modalwindow HTML code? Because it freezes the IE parent window entirely, I can't run the developer tool to inspect the elements.

Comment: Give it a try in Chrome, If it shows iframe in chrome. You can fetch xpath and try it for IE.

Comment: @HemSa, The product is only supported in IE. Maybe because of existence of these modal windows :(

Answer (score 0):

The only option that I could figure out to handle this modal window was to user `Robot` class to manually take control of my operating system from my JAVA code for inputting the details. Since the focus was automatically coming to the child browser window, all I needed to do was type the userId, press TAB, type the password, press TAB and then press ENTER.